# adding non-persistent variables to nsmangedobject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a subclass of an NSManagedObject, and I'd like to add a couple ivars to keep track of some book-keeping. I don't want these vars to persist, and so that is why I don't include them as part of the data model.

I'm having trouble finding the proper way of doing this.

- should I just create ivars in my class, create the corresponding property and then synthesis them in the implementation?
- should I not create ivars, and instead just declare the property and then @dynamic the property in the implmentation?
- is there some other approach i should be taking?

And should I be doing all the customization in the my NSManagedObject subclass, or should I be creating a subclass of my subclass, so that if I change my data model I won't lose all my customizations when I get xcode to generate my NSManagedObject subclass automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each attribute for `NSManagedObject` has a checkbox named **transient**. This way you'll have dynamic accessors for the object without actually persisting the property value itself. Look for checkbox right under the text field for attribute name entry.

[image]

**UPDATE** If you don't want to create a migration because of new attributes, make standard ivars

```
@interface MyMO : NSManagedObject {
    NSString *_nonPersistentAttribute;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nonPersistentAttribute;

@end

@implementation MyMO

@synthesize nonPersistentAttribute=_nonPersistentAttribute;

@end
```

Comment: making modifications to transient attributes will mark the NSManagedObject as dirty. Is there any preferred way of adding extra vars without causing the object to think it needs to be re-saved? And I don't need undo support. Thanks

Comment: Then just add iVars the usual way and `@synthesize` the accessors.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting two alternatives. I have successfully used the second once, but now I only get the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception whenever I try to access the transient property. Any idea?

Comment: If your attribute is transient - make sure you have `@property` for that attribute in class'es interface as well as `@dynamic` its implementation.

Comment: @thibaultd I know this is old, but just for anyone reading it... I had the same problem, and I knew it was something stupid: I had forgotten to make sure the entity Class in the model editor actually matched my NSManagedObject subclass name. So basically it was looking for my transient property on a vanilla NSManagedObject.

Comment: Ha ha, thank you for following up! We moved from core data some time ago :)

Comment: I suspect this solution would create a memory leak, without a release in the dealloc.

Answer (score 10):

The documentation for `NSManagedObject` has a section called *Custom Instance Variables*. It discusses both approaches.

Both transient, modeled attributes and ivars are good solutions. It depends on taste and style.

One **very important** point to remember if you use ivars: You need to clear out ivars in `- (void)didTurnIntoFault` and set any initial values in `- (void)awakeFromFetch` and `- (void)awakeFromInsert`. You need to **not** touch any modeled attributes or relationships inside `-didTurnIntoFault` or else you'll get in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Wise,

To your first question re: ivars, you have two choices standard ivars or transient attributes on your entity. The big difference between the two is that the transient attributes participate in the change/dirty/undo aspects of Core Data. If your ivars don't need that, then don't use the transient attributes. (Yes, use `@property` and `@synthesize` for your ivars.)

To your second question re: where to make the changes? I am somewhat of a luddite. The header patterns automatically generated by Xcode are pretty simple. Hence, I use the auto generated files for the first time I create an entity and edit in my changes thereafter. Frankly, you don't change your model data structures very often. Hence, adding a few lines here and there to both .h&.m files isn't a big cost. There are other mechanisms. Wolf Rentzch's mogenerator system is well respected and useful. That said, I'm not convinced that mogenerator solves a problem faced by modern Objective-C v2 Core Data programmers. (Obj-C v2 has made many things easier for Core Data programmers.)

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Here is a convenient pattern I have used in the past:

Create a category of your class and put it into an additional source file, such as `ManagedObject+Support.h`. Remember, in the interface declaration you just use brackets like this:

```
@interface ManagedObject (Support)
// declare your variables and methods
@end
```

In this way, you can change things around without having to modify your managed object model.  (Changing the MOM has many issues with repopulated databases, migration, etc.). When you change the model, you can generate the class files again without loosing the code in the category.